# Accessing extended properties of a List class from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, inheritance

I have a class which inherits from List and adds some more properties to this base class as follows:

```
public class MyNewList: List<string>
{
    public string MyNewProperty { get; set; }
}
```

I have an MVC controller which returns this kind of class:

```
public JsonResult GetModel()
{
    var model = new MyNewList() { "1", "2", "3" };
    model.MyNewProperty = "I want to be shown!!!";
    return Json(model);
}
```

My problem is that whenever I make an ajax call to server and receive this kind of class, I don't have access to MyNewProperty. It always returns undefined for MyNewProperty, but JavaScript treats the object as a list:

```
$http(...
    function success(result) {
        console.log(result) // ["1", "2", "3"]
        console.log(result.myNewProperty); // undefined
    }
```

I know that it is suggested that we should not inherit from List class but this is an existing class and logic in the project and I cannot change it. I have to find a way to send this object to JavaScript anyway.

Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that if you change your model as given follow, we can get required result:

```
public class MyNewList
    {
        public List<string> data { get; set; }
        public string myNewProperty { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller method will be like that

```
 public JsonResult GetModel()
        {
            var model = new MyNewList();
            model.data=new List<string>(){ "1", "2", "3" };
            model.myNewProperty = "I want to be shown!!!";
            return Json(model);
        }
```

JavaScript Ajax call will be like that

```
  $http(...
        function success(result) {
            console.log(result.data) // ["1", "2", "3"]
            console.log(result.myNewProperty); // "I want to be shown!!!"
        }
```

alternately if we make some changes in Controller method without changing model structure. you can try this:

```
public JsonResult GetModel()
        {
            var model = new MyNewList(){ "1", "2", "3" };
            model.MyNewProperty = "I want to be shown!!!";
            var result=new {Data=model,newProperty=model.MyNewProperty};
           return Json(result);
        }
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but, as I mentioned at the end of my question, I cannot change the structure of the class for legacy purposes. I have no choice but to inherit from List class.

Comment: can you change in controller method? if made some changes in controller method this can be acheived

Comment: Yes, that can do the job. Thanks. However, still looking/waiting for a better answer since in this case, I have to type and fill every single properties which causes duplication/inconsistency if I happen to forget to give a value to one property. Otherwise, I think this is the way.Maybe if I could add a special attribute to MyNewList class, my problem would be fixed more easily...